# Get the URL of the file where is declared the function

Tags: javascript

I can't find anything on the web.
The keyword I used all give me more traditional answers.

I am working on an embeder for a Flash file.
I want to have a folder with the flash file and the javascript code to embed it properly.

My question is, how do I get the path to my Flah file?
I have the relative URL from the js file, but if I make a request from the js it will take the URL of the html page, right?

In Flash, the behaviour is the same, but you can get the url where the SWF file is hosted.
I this it also exists with PHP.
How do you do that with a javascript file?

I know I must have the URL in the HTML anyhow, since I load the js file.
And I can send it to the function I call as a parameter.
But I am trying to make it as simple as possible to instal, so if this function exist I'd like to know of it.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Finaly, I used some PHP, who can locate himself easily using $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], to add some parameter to a javascript file.

You embed the PHP request the same way you would a javascript file.

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your page is constructed you can do it by using the trick that (all?) browsers block when they encounter a vanilla `<script>` tag (no [async](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) attr used here).

The following would be in your separate JS file (for simplicity I use PrototypeJS syntax and assume the `<script>` tag that loaded this script is located in `<head>`):

```
// src will be the src of THIS JS file, as the browser has blocked
var src = $$("head script").last().src;

// root just takes the src up to the last '/'
var root = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access the url from within your javascript through [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) (that's what you're looking for if my understanding of the question is right).

Comment: No, you didn't understand me properly, but that's my falt.
I am lacking the proper vocabulary.
Thanks ayway.